# How to activate FP6293 converter from EN pin?

Tags: switches, integrated-circuit, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, buck-boost

I'm making a portable device which is powered by a lithium battery and boosted with a FP6293 boost converter IC. I want to turn on and off the device from a switch that activates and deactivates the FP6293, I know I can do this from the EN pin, but the documentation is not really clear in that aspect:

[image]

Following the application circuit, the EN pin is directly connected to the power input (VIN), so I guess the boost IC activates when Vin enters the circuit. Can I put a switch between the Vcc and EN pin to activate and the activate the IC to I can control the shutdown and power up of the device? I don't know if I should put a resistor, connect it to the ground, the documentation is really poor in that aspect...

Here is the datasheet I'm using: https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/Feeling-Tech-FP6293XR-G1_C83576.pdf

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: My golden rule is that chips with poor documentation don't get used in a design unless there are no feasible alternatives.....

Comment: *Can I put a switch between the Vcc and EN pin to activate and the activate the IC to I can control the shutdown and power up of the device?* Probably yes, a pull down resistor (like 100 kohm) and a switch to Vcc might also work. But since you need a toggle switch (EN does not work like push-on, push-off) you could just put a toggle switch in series with Vcc.

Comment: Following your answer, I put a switch just in front of the EN pin like this: https://i.snipboard.io/4a6rJM.jpg So I can leave the EN pin open and when I want to activate the circuit I push the switch.

Comment: What controls the voltage level on the EN input with the switch open?

Comment: When the switch is open EN is connected to ground, so there's no input until the switch is down and feeds EN with the input voltage, which I guess activates the circuit.

Comment: If you were to take an oscilloscope and look at what happens as that switch opens and closes, you'd see [contact bounce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce). Maybe the FP6293 can handle that, or maybe it fails prematurely. No details in the datasheet.